# Using one model class within multiple DbQuerys

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I have many tables in DB that share the same schema; Example:
Table1 (id, nameE, nameF)
Table2 (id, nameE, nameF)...

Using EF/Asp.net Core3+ to retrieve the data, I have done this:

my DbContext example:

```
     public DbQuery<ValueList1> Table1 { get; set; }
     public DbQuery<ValueList2> Table2 { get; set; }
```

now my Model ValueList1 and ValueList2 contains the same parameters

```
    [Table("Table1")]
    public class ValueList1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nameE{ get; set; }
        public string nameF{ get; set; }
    }
    [Table("Table2")]
    public class ValueList2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nameE{ get; set; }
        public string nameF{ get; set; }
    }
```

I can successfully retrieve the data  _dbContext.Table1; and _dbContext.Table2;

My question: How can I use one model instead of duplicating and having duplicate files.

I have tried that but it failed on line  [Table("Table1, Table2")]

```
     public DbQuery<ValueList> Table1 { get; set; }
     public DbQuery<ValueList> Table2 { get; set; }

     [Table("Table1, Table2")]
     public class ValueList1
      {
         public int id { get; set; }
        public string nameE{ get; set; }
        public string nameF{ get; set; }
      }
```

Comment: I believe that the EF maps the tables with entity types strongly based on the entity types. So each entity type represents just one table, no way to use one entity type to mean any tables (no matter the schema is the same or not). So in this case, the best you can do is try declaring a common `interface` and declare other entity classes to implement that same interface. That way you can take advantage of design-time features (such as error checking each time updating to the common interface or auto-implement the class without typing, ...).

Comment: Or you can declare a base class containing all the properties, that base class is abstract and of course cannot be an entity type. The other classes inheriting from that can be entity types.

Answer (score 2):

To be the base class for same properties, and inherite the base class

```
 public class ValueList1
  {
     public int id { get; set; }
    public string nameE{ get; set; }
    public string nameF{ get; set; }
  }
 [Table("Table 1")]
 public class Table1 : ValueList1
  {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @WilliamChow's answer, you can then put properties on your DbContext like

```
public IQueryable<ValueList> Table1 => this.Set<Table1>();
public IQueryable<ValueList> Table2 => this.Set<Table2>();
```

Since IQueryable supports [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).